# Excel hours worked calculation, based on specific time shifts

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel with working hours in format Starting: `15:30 (A1) and finishing: 01:00 (B1)`.

I would like to calculate the hours that I worked as nightshift (C1). The night shift is between 22:00 and 06:00. So if I work for example 17:00 to 02:15, I should get the number 04:15 as night shift hours. I work from 22:00 to 09.15 I should get 8 nightshift hours. I got the time difference with this
`=MOD(B2-A2;1)` but this gets the whole shift and not the night ones only. Any suggestions?

It seems that this code works for one pair of columns, but I cannot figure out how to sum the results. The excel is separated into columns, where every date has 2 columns for Starting and Ending shift

```
=MOD(D4-C4;1)*24-(D4<C4)*(22-6)-MEDIAN(D4*24;6;22)+MEDIAN(C4*24;6;22)
```

The ideal would be to have a formula to this result

```
=MOD(D4-C4;1)*24-(D4<C4)*(22-6)-MEDIAN(D4*24;6;22)+MEDIAN(C4*24;6;22)+MOD(F4-E4;1)*24-(F4<E4)*(22-6)-MEDIAN(F4*24;6;22)+MEDIAN(E4*24;6;22)+MOD(H4-G4;1)*24-(H4<G4)*(22-6)-MEDIAN(H4*24;6;22)+MEDIAN(G4*24;6;22)
```

etc, but more compact way

[image]

Comment: Are the working hours starting at 15:00 and ending 01:00 (of the next day)?, so why do you have the night shift up to 06:00?, please clarify it or update your question. Thanks

Comment: The night shift is controlled by others. If you work some of the night hours you get morw rewarded. But one day you can work for example 15.00 to 23.00 and the other from 01:00 to 09:00.

Comment: Still not clear what is the range of the Night Shift. Please clarify it. Thanks.

Comment: The night hours that pays extra is between 22.00 and 06.00. But shifts are not standard hours. You can work from 15.00 to 23.00 (so you will get 1 hour extra pay), or for example 23.00-07.00 so you will get 7 hours extra pay

Comment: It seems that this code works for one pair of columns, but i cannot figure out how to sum the results. The excel is seperated into columns, where every date has 2 columns for Starting and Ending shift

=MOD(D4-C4;1)24-(D4<C4)(22-6)-MEDIAN(D424;6;22)+MEDIAN(C424;6;22)

The ideal would be to have a formula to this result =MOD(D4-C4;1)24-(D4<C4)(22-6)-MEDIAN(D424;6;22)+MEDIAN(C424;6;22)+ MOD(F4-E4;1)24-(F4<E4)(22-6)-MEDIAN(F424;6;22)+MEDIAN(E424;6;22)+ MOD(H4-G4;1)24-(H4<G4)(22-6)-MEDIAN(H424;6;22)+MEDIAN(G424;6;22) etc, but more compact way

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all input times are relative to `1/0/1900` (only time portion information). Therefore you need to consider when the date refers to the next day (adding `1`). The condition for the end date is that if `start > end`, then the `end` date refers to the next day (`+1`). We take into account the above for the solution.

Assuming no excel version constraints as per the tags listed in the question, you can use the following formula in `F2`:

```
=LET(start,A2:A5, end,B2:B5, ns,D2, ne,D3+1, eEff,IF(end<start, end+1, end),
 CALC, LAMBDA(isStart, MAP(start, eEff, LAMBDA(x,y, IF(y < ns, 0, 
  MEDIAN(IF(isStart, x, y), ns, ne))))), a, CALC(TRUE), b, CALC(FALSE),b-a)
```

I created a user `LAMBDA` function `CALC` just to avoid repetition of a similar calculation for the actual start (`a`) and end (`b`) of the working night interval. As you can see from the formula the night end (`ne`) has been adjusted to consider the next day. Similarly, we do the adjustment for the `end` time, calculating the effective end time (`eEff`) considering the next day when the end time (`end`) is lower than the start time (`start`).

We use `MEDIAN` to identify the actual interval in both cases. Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

where `0:00` means no time consumed during the night shift. The rest is just to use the correct format: `hh:mm` in the output to show durations during the night shift.

If you show the input data in numeric format, you can see the times referred to the first valid year in Excel (`<= 1`):

[image: excel output2]

That is why we need to convert `ne` and `end` (in case it represents the next day), but it depends on whether or not you want to consider the next day in your input data. So for row `2` it represents `01:00` of the current day (`0.04`) so in the formula, we treat it as: `01:00` of the next day `(1.04`)

Comment: This works well for 1 day of work. =MOD(D4-C4;1)*24-(D4<C4)*(22-6)-MEDIAN(D4*24;6;22)+MEDIAN(C4*24;6;22)     How do i use it for all the other columns to have a sum for all the month? C4 is starting time at day 1, and D4 is ending time at day 1, E4 is starting day at Day 2, and F4 is ending time at day 2, and so on

Comment: @GiwrgosRad your question refers to just one single value. I added several start/end to consider several scenarios.  Please review your question or better create a new one with a more generic scenario (for more than one day of work). It is difficult to provide a solution without an input data sample and the expected output. Please confirm if my solution provided works for a single interval start/end. It is difficult to understand somebody else formula, it is better to explain the problem, so the community can help you with several different approaches.

Comment: i get the error too many arguments

Comment: @GiwrgosRad what is your excel version, I provided evidence this works. I have O365.

Comment: doublechecked. i get #NAME?

Comment: Are you sure you have O365 version? You can check it works by clicking the following [link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlZxw2GG3C7Ih2sUyHh13TdLjnsV?e=G9eOYT)